# Basic Survival Facts in Finite Group Theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

What are some basic facts of finite group theory used over and over again, so that pro's does not even think about them anymore (and even implicitly contained in many arguments). I mean facts comparable to those given [here](http://www.calpoly.edu/~epearse/resources/Math145-Topology/basic-survival.pdf) and [here](http://www.calpoly.edu/~epearse/resources/Math145-Topology/compactness-mantras.pdf) for basic math and topology. To begin the list, here I think the following basic facts should be mentioned:

- a subgroup is the unique Sylow $p$-subgroup iff it is normal
- the elements of two disjoint normal subgroups commute with each other
- if two elements commute and have coprime order, the order is multiplicative, conversely if we could write the order of an element as the product of two coprime numbers, then there exists unique commuting elements with these orders which product yields that element

Maybe some other facts about centralisers, commutators, normalisers etc?

More advanced "survival facts" might be:

- the Sylow theorems
- the orbit-stabilier theorem (and therefore the basic fact that the index of the normaliser equals the number of conjugates of some subgroup)
- the class equation

But I am looking for more basic ones.

**EDIT**: To be more specific for what I am asking, see MJD comment below, from which I quote:

> "I think looking not for things that are basic or advanced, but for things that are useful but not always stated explicitly [...]"

Comment: I think it would be remiss to not mention the Isomorphism theorems.

Comment: Yes! I think it would be also nice if some straight consequences (no full proofs) could be mentioned. For example, for the isomorphism theorem that each cyclic subgroup is ismorphic to a quotient group of $\mathbb Z$ by the epimorphism $i \mapsto g^i$ for some generator of the cyclic group (and therefore $\mathbb Z$ and its quotients are essentially the only cyclic groups up to isomorphism).

Comment: Lagrange's theorem is used incessantly, but perhaps that is too elementary?

Comment: To be strict, it should be included, but in fact this is so elementary that I even did not considered it. So maybe we should restrict on facts that are simple, but not so much that you could read them everywhere, more such kind of facts novices stumble upon, but which become obvious as you become more aquainted with the topic.

Comment: Someone recently pointed out here that a subgroup is normal if and only if it is a union of conjugacy classes. In thirty years of group theory this had somehow escaped my notice. Is that the sort of thing you are looking for?

Comment: I don't understand how “a subgroup is the unique Sylow $p$-subgroup iff it is normal” could be considered *less* advanced than the Sylow theorems themselves. Can you please clear this up?

Comment: @MJD: Yes, what you first mentioned is such a fact. Such things that are sometimes not explicitly mentioned, but used. Yes you need to know the Sylow theorems to apply the other fact, but it is a fact so basic that is does not even need to mentioned in follow up proofs (after exposed to the Sylow theorems), so that a novice who first heard about Sylow theorems might stumble upon if he has not fully internalised all of them, do you get what I mean? Not basic in the sense of logical derivation, but basic in the sense, used by practitioners over and over again (and could involve advanced notion).

Comment: I think looking not for things that are basic or advanced, but for things that are useful but not always stated explicitly. Lagrange's theorem is always stated and proved early in an introductory course, but the examples you gave, while similarly elementary, aren't always mentioned.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant :)